# Error recording an RTSP stream without transcoding

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to record RTSP streams from several security cameras. I have been successfully *transcoding* each stream for months now, but since this requires considerable CPU power, I'd like to simply *copy* each stream to disk in it's original H.264 format.

Whenever I try this, I receive and error similar to this (the "current" value varies):

> Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -62743;

I've stripped most of the options I was using, although I really do want to keep -xerror so that FFmpeg quits when it encounters an error:

```
ffmpeg.exe -xerror -i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.135 -an -vcodec copy test.mp4
```

And I still get this:

```
    ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers  
    built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)   
    configuration: --enable-gpl
    --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib   
    libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100   
    libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100   
    libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100   
    libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100   
    libavfilter     6. 82.100 / 6. 82.100   
    libswscale      4.  6.100 / 4.  6.100  
    libswresample   2.  7.100 / 2.  7.100   
    libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
    [udp @ 0000000002533b60] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required) 
    [udp @ 0000000000ec97a0] 'circular_buffer_size' option was set but it is not supported on this build (pthread support is required) 
    Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.135':   Metadata:
        title           : RTSP Session/2.0   Duration: N/A, start: 0.837144, bitrate: N/A
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 7 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 14 tbc Output
    #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':   Metadata:
        title           : RTSP Session/2.0
    y    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 7 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc 
    Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy) 
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help 

    [mp4 @ 00000000036b8340] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: -62743; aborting.

    Conversion failed!
```

Can anyone explain what the problem is and/or suggest the appropriate flags to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried outputting to `test.ts`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that, same result unfortunately